# Using prototype to store a property instead of getter in JavScript class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, prototype

So, I'm going through eloquent javascript's [platform game](https://eloquentjavascript.net/16_game.html#p_qFX0r+uydc) and in this class, why are we storing `size` property in the prototype?

The description says:

> The size property is the same for all instances of Player, so we store it on the prototype rather than on the instances themselves. We could have used a getter like type, but that would create and return a new Vec object every time the property is read, which would be wasteful. (Strings, being immutable, don’t have to be re-created every time they are evaluated.)

But I couldn't understand that. Help me out!

```js
class Player {
  constructor(pos, speed) {
    this.pos = pos;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  get type() { return "player"; }

  static create(pos) {
    return new Player(pos.plus(new Vec(0, -0.5)),
                      new Vec(0, 0));
  }
}

Player.prototype.size = new Vec(0.8, 1.5);
```

Also, if anyone has completed the game, can anyone tell me how the x and y coordinates are taken here in `new Vec(0.8, 1.5)`, `new Vec(0, -0.5)` and `new Vec(0, 0)`. I' m having hard time understand it. Thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand? Rather than store a size property in every object, it just stores it once in the prototype, which all the instances inherit.

Comment: I don't understand this: 
> We could have used a getter like type, but that would create and return a new Vec object every time the property is read, which would be wasteful.

Comment: Every time you call `new Vec()` it has to construct a new `Vec` object. Since it never changes and all the instances are the same, that would be redundant.

Comment: Returning a string literal has no overhead because the JavaScript compiler knows that nothing has to be constructed. So it's OK to have a function for `get type`.

Comment: how would the getter look like if used instead of prototype?

Comment: `get size() { return new Vec(0.8, 1.5); }`

Comment: thnks that makes sense now @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing on prototype is similar to static properties in other languages (eg. Java)
That means there is only single Vec instance shared across all Player instances.

When you access any player's property, iJavaScript first looking for regular property on player instances, if not found looking on class prototype, then parent class prototype and so on.

In this case, it's jut optimization. Instead of creating Vec instance for each player there exist only single on in a memory. In other words you can look at as constant.